# Velocity template charset

Tags: java, html, character, velocity

I am new at using velocity templates and in a few I have created, most of the templates work fine but if I add different characters to the templates it sometimes does not work.

How do you know what characters velocity templates allow?

Comment: Could you add to the question what characters are causing trouble?

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't really provide too much details, it is a bit hard to help blindly, but having been in the same trousers myself, my `0xFF`th sense feels that you have troubles with the default encoding being different than that of the template.

You should *explicitly* specify encoding wherever possible, and in this case it is possible. Use the `encoding` parameters when using the templates to supply the required encoding using the functions in `org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity` class:

```
public static Template getTemplate(String name, String encoding);
public static boolean mergeTemplate( String templateName, String encoding, Context context, Writer writer );
```

Instead of the functions omitting the `encoding` parameter:

Recommended reading:

- [Velocity Template Encoding for Internationalization](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#Template_Encoding_for_Internationalization)